# Checkbox hiding with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I prepared this hidden functionality for checkbox with jquery. https://jsfiddle.net/o2c8z5xw/  When Hidden is clicked, checkboxes disappear. How can I do this by default, instead of clicking, when the page is opened?

HTML code:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Hidden" name="Hidden" class="hidden"/>Hidden</label>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />All</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="5" class="selector" />5</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="7" class="selector" />7</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="9" class="selector" />9</label>
</form>
```

Jquery code:

```
$( "#Hidden").on( "click", function() {
    $(".selector").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `toggle` it when the document is ready.

See [updated js fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/o2c8z5xw/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".selector").toggle();
  $("#Hidden").prop('checked', true);

  $("#Hidden").on("click", function() {
     $(".selector").toggle();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding `.selector` using CSS:

```
.selector {
    display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2c8z5xw/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the CSS-based solution with no JS changes.

Hide the `.selector` elements with `display: none`, but also note to add the `checked` attribute to your "Hidden" checkbox so the interface still makes sense (otherwise the toggle behavior will be the opposite of the Hidden checkbox).

```js
$("#Hidden").on("click", function() {
  $(".selector").toggle();
});
```

```css
.selector {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" id="Hidden" name="Hidden" class="hidden" checked />Hidden</label>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />All</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="5" class="selector" />5</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="7" class="selector" />7</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="9" class="selector" />9</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Maarten's solution above, with the nitpick that it makes more sense to add a 'selector-hidden' class to the checkboxes and toggle that instead.

CSS:

```
.selector-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$( "#Hidden").on( "click", function() {
    $(".selector-hidden").toggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pg04yhav/

This way the selectors can be styled using the 'selector' class, but be hidden by toggling the 'selector-hidden' class.